# Existence of a normal cyclic subgroup of order 133

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am following a first class in group theory. How would I proceed to (begin) solving the following question?

Suppose G is a group of order 399. Prove there exists a cyclic normal subgroup of order 133.

Assuming a subgroup of order 133, I know how to prove it is normal. But how would I prove such a subgroup exists? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of $19$-sylow subgroups must be a divisor of $7\times 3$ that is congruent to $1\bmod 19$, the only such divisor is $1$. Therefore the $19$-sylow subgroup is unique and normal.

Let $H$ be this subgroup and $P$ be  a sylow 7-subgroup.

Since $H$ is normal we have that $PH$ is a subgroup, we can prove $|H\cap P|=1$ by Lagrange's theorem, so $PH$ has order $133$.

Proving it is normal is a corollary of the folowing lemma:

If $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is the smallest prime factor of its order then every dubgroup of $G$ of index $p$ is normal.

Comment: I think you don't need the corollary: the number of Sylow $7$-subgroups is also $1$.

Comment: @Bernard but $3\times 19$ is $1\bmod 7$

Comment: Yes but this would imply there $14$ $3$-Sylow subgroups, which isn't congruent to $1$ mod $3$ and doesn't divide $7\times 19$ either.

Comment: @tjeremie you're most welcome